# Additional set of auth views with Rails/Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I have a Ruby on Rails app that uses Devise (and Omniauth) for authentication.

I'm trying to integrate with an iOS app (out of my control) that wants to embed pages from my app. This app needs my pages to have a specific visual appearance, so I want to create an additional set of authentication views.

After digging around in the Devise docs, I've gathered that maybe I need to create a new `devise_scope` block in `routes.rb`:

```
devise_scope :user do
    get    "iosapp/users/sign_in"  => "devise/sessions#iosapp_new"
    post   "iosapp/users/sign_in"  => "devise/sessions#iosapp_create"
    delete "iosapp/users/sign_out" => "devise/sessions#iosapp_destroy"
end
```

And I created a new set of views that correspond to those routes:

```
app/views/devise/sessions/iosapp_new.html.rb
app/views/devise/sessions/iosapp_create.html.rb
app/views/devise/sessions/iosapp_destroy.html.rb
```

But loading **/iosapp/users/sign_in** in the browser leads to a Rails error:

```
undefined method `errors' for nil:NilClass
```

That error stems from line 9 of devise_helper.rb (https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/helpers/devise_helper.rb):

```
module DeviseHelper
  # A simple way to show error messages for the current devise resource. If you need
  # to customize this method, you can either overwrite it in your application helpers or
  # copy the views to your application.
  #
  # This method is intended to stay simple and it is unlikely that we are going to change
  # it to add more behavior or options.
  def devise_error_messages!
    return "" if resource.errors.empty?

    messages = resource.errors.full_messages.map { |msg| content_tag(:li, msg) }.join
    ...
```

I'm obviously doing something wrong here, but can't figure out why `resource` is undefined when called from my "alternate" views. It seems as if I may need to create additional controller methods as well, but I can't find anything in the docs about this.

Am I way off track? Or is there a better way to accomplish my goal than this?

Comment: @Charles, thank you, that did it! Boneheaded error on my part. If you add your comment as an answer, I'll accept it the "official" answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your new views need `form_for resource` - do you have that in place? It can't find the errors on the resource if there is no resource, hence the error on nil.